# MySql how to automatically apply discounts?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Lets say client ordered 3 products

Order products table:

```
id | order_id | product_id |  price
1  |   1      |      2     |   10
2  |   1      |      2     |   10
3  |   1      |      2     |   10
```

Orders table:

```
id | total_price
1  |     30
```

and now I want MySql to apply special discount that makes 3rd item free during specific period of time. So as result I will get

```
id | total_price
1  |     20
```

I'm using MySql 5.6, php(symfony 2, doctrine ORM) and wondering what is the best way to create and handle such scenarios.

Comment: This logic does not belong in the mysql layer, it belongs in the php layer.

Comment: All prices are 10, so the total is simply the total, less 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply discounts during periods you have to design code to support this. A design could look as follows:

Create a discount table:

```
CREATE TABLE discount(
  discount_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  rule VARCHAR(400),
  start_date DATE,
  end_date DATE
);
```

The discount `rule` can be a JSON string containing the instructions. These instructions can differ every time so this way your table is the same all the time.
A possible structure for the JSON for this discount is:

```
{"ruleType":"multipleProductDiscount","ruleValue":"3"}
```

You can then use a `CASE` statement to apply the different discount rules when you process them in the code.

The start/end date are just a way to prevent of having to load and process all the rules every time. So a query retrieving the data from the `discount` table only gets active data instead:

```
SELECT * FROM discount WHERE somedate BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! Thought of features like using triggers or stored procedures but they seems to be working on simple cases or "hardcoded" into mysql. Still in my DB i have 2 types of discounts 1. simple - n percent discount for carryout or special offers. 2. buy n products(of the same type or category) and get one free. And i need to create wizard so users can insert their own discount scenarios. Will try moving this way.

Comment: A stored procedure with a trigger can also process a JSON (no reason why not). Look into MariaDB (one on one MySQL replacement) with JSON columns for easy access to the JSON data.